# How can i update one PostgreSQL database and sync changes/updates to another PostgreSQL database on another server

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql

I have a django website with PostgreSQL database hosted on one server with a different company and a mirror of that django website is hosted on another server with another company which also have the same exact copy of the PostgreSQL database . How can i sync or update that in real time or interval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgresql has master-slave replication. Try That!